# reading the hex file of atmega8

Tags: arduino, microcontroller, avr, atmega, avrdude

I want   to  make  a clone  of   a  circuit with atmega8 i  have  the schematics  and  PCB  is  OK   the  problem   is   i want  to  read  the hex  file   on  the atmega8  chip   and my  question  is   is  it  doable?   and   if   i  want  to detect  the  type of the  chip on   avrdudess  is  it necessary  to write  the  lock byte  and  HIGH fuses  and low fuses  or  just   i need  to  predict  only  the lock byte?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. *the problem is i want to read the hex file on the atmega8 chip and my question is is it doable?*

   Provided that lock bits are not programmed, it is possible to read the contents of both flash and EEPROM by adding `-U flash:r:flash.hex:i -U eeprom:r:eeprom.hex:i` options to the invocation of `avrdude`.
2. *and if i want to detect the type of the chip on avrdudess is it necessary to write the lock byte and HIGH fuses and low fuses or just i need to predict only the lock byte?*

   You don't need to write anything to the chip in order detect its type.
   I guess that all you have to do is to click the "Detect" button.
3. *... (see comments under this answer)*

   Maybe we should approach the problem from a different angle: do you have an ISP programmer or an Arduino board?
   If you have a programmer, then try to use it to read the memory of your chip.
   If you have an Arduino, burn it with ArduinoISP, connect to atmega8 as showed on the bottom of this page -- don't worry about different chip: the pins that we are interested in (reset, vcc, gnd, xtal, sck, miso, mosi) have the same "numbers" on both atmega168 and atmega8.
   **Don't forget about 10 uF capacitor accross reset and ground of the Arduino.**

   **Don't use the "Burn Bootloader" command from the tutorial I linked in the previous comment.**

   Instead, run AVRDUDESS, select avrisp as the programmer, set baud rate to 19200 and click on the "detect" button.
   If it works, you can read the flash.

   *Hint: you can tick "Do not write" option to be sure that you will not accidentaly override the contents of your chip's memory.*
4. *i have one more question .do i need to read the eeprom to make a clone ? or just i need only the flash?*

   The safest way is to read it.
   Whether it's really needed, depends on the program -- how it's written, whether eeprom is used to store configuration (if it's used at all) or some constants, etc.
   If it's used to store configuration, then probably the special case when all data reads `0xFF` is somehow handled, e. g. default config is loaded from the flash.
   If constants are stored in eeprom, then without copying it's contents the program won't work as expected.
   **As you can see, it's safer to just copy it, unless you have a good counterargument (some technical problems or you are absolutely sure that the program in flash doesn't use the eeprom or something else).**
5. *Sorry i made a mistake i mean to WRITE the flash and eeprom to an empty atmega8 i already make the read now i want to make a clone how can i do that i have the HIGH fuses and low fuses and lockbyte i red them with avrdudess*
   *and do i need to write the flash only or i must write the eeprom too*

   If you want to make an exact copy, do the following:

   - read the eeprom and flash memories, fuse and lock bytes of the original chip
   - (put the original chip aside)
   - perform an erase cycle on the chip you want to become a copy of the original one (make sure EESAVE is unprogrammed)
   - program the fuse bytes (be cautious about RSTDISBL and similar bits)
   - (connect crystal/resonator/RC/... if necessary -- see 'Clock Sources' section in the datasheet)
   - program the eeprom
   - **check the "Disable flash erase (-D)" checkbox,** program the flash memory and lock bits (it's preferable to do it with one invocation of `avrdude`, make sure `-U:flash:w:...` option is given before `-U:lock:w:...`)

   **You must use an ISP programmer, ArduinoISP should suffice.**

Comment: thank  you  for your time   i tried   do  click   on  detect  only  but  i get 
"arduino stk500_getsync() not in sync resp=0x30 "

Comment: I   have  another  atmega8  with Arduino  bootloader  and  if  I click on  detect   I  get  the same   error   but  if  I  change  the baud rate    and  click  on  detect   the  chip  detected  by  the GUI . I  have  another atmega8  with different bootloader   and I changed  the  baud rate nothing happened  I get  the same error

Comment: Try the following baud rates: 1200, 2400, 4800, 9600, 19200, 38400, 57600, 115200.

Comment: ok  I'll   try   and  let  you know  the  results   .thanks :)

Comment: hi Aleksander  , unfortunately, none of the  above baud rates  come up with reading the type of the chip  is it necessary to give the lock  byte to  read   the  chip?

Comment: Could you explain why do you think that it is necessary to set the lock bits before attempting to detect the type of the chip? I don't see how LB could affect the proccess of detecting.

Comment: Maybe we should approach the problem from a different angle: do you have an ISP programmer or an Arduino board? If you have a programmer, then try to use it to read the memory of your chip. If you have an Arduino, burn it with ArduinoISP, connect to atmega8 as showed on the bottom of [this page](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoISP) -- don't worry about different chip: the pins that we are interested in (reset, vcc, gnd, xtal, sck, miso, mosi) have the same "numbers" on both atmega168 and atmega8. **Don't forget about 10 uF capacitor accross reset and ground of the Arduino.**

Comment: **Don't use the "Burn Bootloader" command from the tutorial I linked in the previous comment.**

Comment: Instead, run AVRDUDESS, select avrisp as the programmer, set baud rate to 19200 and click on the "detect" button. If it works, you can read the flash. _Hint: you can tick "Do not write" option to be sure that you will not accidentaly override the contents of your chip's memory._

Comment: i have  one more question  .do  i need  to  read the eeprom  to  make a clone  ? or just  i need only the flash?

Comment: I answered in the answer above.

Comment: Sorry  i made  a  mistake  i mean  to WRITE   the flash and eeprom to  an empty atmega8 i  already make the read now i want to make a clone  how can  i  do that i have the HIGH fuses and low fuses and lockbyte  i red  them with avrdudess

Comment: and  do  i need to write the flash only  or  i must  write the eeprom too